# Почему if-ы в цикле не идут по порядку? (Java)

Tags: java, циклы

```
    int moneyUser;
    Scanner money = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Привет! Сколько нужно разменять? : ");
    moneyUser = money.nextInt();
    int coin = 1;


   while (moneyUser > 0){
       if(moneyUser > 25){
            moneyUser -= 25;
            coin++;   
        }else if (moneyUser < 25){
            moneyUser -= 10;
            coin++;
        }else if (moneyUser < 10){
            moneyUser -= 5;
            coin++;
        } else if (moneyUser < 5){
            moneyUser -= 1;
            coin++;
        } else {
    System.out.println(coin);
}
       }
```

Дано: монетки номиналом 25, 10, 5, 1 цент

Программа должна:

```
  Спросить пользователя, сколько сдачи нужно выдать
    Посчитать минимальное количество монет, с помощью которых можно это сделать
```

Comment: Что значит "не идут по порядку"? Что именно происходит и что вас в этом не устраивает?

Comment: D-side, если например ввести число 25, то число монет для сдачи, в данном случае будет по идеи 1, так и получается но цикл выводит это число бесконечно, а вот если ввести 35, по идеи должно получиться 2 монеты, 25 и 10, но ответ даже не отображается, программа просто завершается

ЗЫ. Я  новичок, не умею еще правильно вырожаться )

Comment: Изначально 25 монет -- вычитаем 25 (становится 0), добавляем монету и возвращаемся к началу. Для ноля монет первый подходящий -- второй блок (ведь 0 < 25): вычитаем 10 (из нуля!) и возвращаемся к началу. Уже что-то пошло не так, не находите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Будьте внимательнее, программа зацикливается, потому что Вы не правильно прописали условия в `if`-ах. Если Вы введете число 25, то не выполниться не одно условие (`25 > 25 = false` и `25 < 25 = false`). Исправьте условие `if(moneyUser > 25)` на `if(moneyUser >= 25)` и все будет работать. Еще нужно исправить `else if (moneyUser < 25)` на `else if (moneyUser < 25 && moneyUser >= 10)`, так как если, допустим, Вы введете число 2, то теоретически могут выполниться три последних цикла: `else if (moneyUser < 25)`, `else if (moneyUser < 10)`, `else if (moneyUser < 5)` и Вы можете получить отрицательное число.

Comment: спасибо, и вправду не заметил ) впредь буду повнимательней